# Web Deploy Backup for Single service or application

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I've been following the following link for our automatic deployments:

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups

However, we group lots of web services under a single site so we don't have to use multiple host names to bind to each service. The problem with Web Deploy is that it backs up the WHOLE site will all of our services.

We only want to backup a single application underneath the site. How is this possible with Web Deploy and backups?